# How to access the "name" of things in my array list that is an array list of my interface type?

Tags: java, arraylist, interface

The title is wordy and possibly confusing but I am not sure how to make it better...I want to be able to access values in my array list and print them out.

I have an interface called ThingBagInterface.  This ThingBagInterface only has one method, and looks like this:

```
interface ThingBagInterface {
    public String getType();
}
```

I now have a class called ThingBag, it's a bag that hold a bunch of different stuff, such as Creatures, Buildings etc.

In my ThingBag class, I have initialized all of my Creatures like this:

```
public void initCreatures(){
     waterSnake = new Creature("Water Snake", Terrain.SWAMP, false, false, false, false, 1, 0);
    etc...
}
```

and then I have a function populateBag() that looks like this:

```
public void populateBag(){
    initCreatures();

    bag.add(bears);
}
```

My array list definition is in ThingBag and looks like this:

```
ArrayList<ThingBagInterface> bag = new ArrayList<ThingBagInterface>();
```

My Creature constructor looks like this:

```
    public Creature(String n, Terrain startTerrain, boolean flying, boolean magic, boolean charge, boolean ranged, int combat, int o){
        name = n;
        flyingCreature = flying;
        magicCreature = magic;
        canCharge = charge;
        rangedCombat = ranged;
        combatValue = combat;
        owned = o;
    }
```

I want to print out the name of the bear.

So in main I am doing this:

```
ThingBag tb = new ThingBag();
tb.populateBag();
for(int i= 0; i<tb.bag.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(i+". "+tb.bag.get(i));
}
```

Why can I not access the name in my bag?  If I wasn't using an interface I would be able to say:

```
System.out.println(i+". "+tb.bag.get(i).name)
```

But I can't now.  Any ideas on how I can access that value?  I can only access memory addresses now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `bag` variable is declared as

```
ArrayList<ThingBagInterface> bag ...
```

This, conceptually, means that it contains at least `ThingBagInterface` objects. It can contain any type of `ThingBagInterface`, but it has to at least be a `ThingBagInterface`.

What this also means is that the compiler can only guarantee that it contains `ThingBagInterface` and therefore you can only interact with its elements as `ThingBagInterface` instances.

`name` is not a field that exists on the `ThingBagInterface` type, it exists on `Creature`.

You can either cast the returned value of `bag.get(i)` or declare a `getName()` method of `ThingBagInterface`, implement it in the sub types, and invoke it in your loop.

Comment: Thank you, this is my first time trying to use an interface so I am going to make a lot of dumb mistakes until I actually figure it out.  Thank you again.

Comment: Note that if you're going to cast the elements to `Creature`, there's not much reason to have a `ThingBagInterface` at all. `ArrayList<Creature>` would work better.

Comment: @Sarah Take note of what user2357112 just said. Do you have many `ThingBagInterface`? Do they all have a `name`? Consider making a base class for all of them.

Comment: They do all have a name. I'm unsure if I want an interface or inheritance really.  I did have an array list of Creatures, but I needed to change it because my Array List needs to be holding several different types of things.  They do all have a name, so maybe that is where I should go, but name is all they have in common.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to design the `ThingBagInterface` interface more sensibly. Is having a name a requirement? If so, the interface needs a way to access the object's name. (This needs to be a method, as interfaces can't specify fields.) While we're at it, picking a more informative name than `ThingBagInterface` would be a good idea.

Comment: it's an interface for a bag that holds "things" which is the game piece names for the board game I'm trying to implement, so it's pretty informative, but I do get what you are trying to say, so thank you

Comment: @Sarah: The name doesn't give any information about how it relates to `ThingBag`. It sounds like `ThingBag` is supposed to implement it, rather than the things contained in a bag. Imagine if the interface for passengers in a car was called `CarInterface`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe do a cast like so `System.out.println(i+". "+(((Creature)tb.bag.)get(i));`

This is because the interface does not have a name attribute. Remember fields in interfaces are always implicitly public static and final.

I hope this helps.